# How to create a regional virtual network in Azure portal for use with AD Domain Services

Tags: active-directory, office365, azure, virtual-network

My organization uses office365 for it's email. It is the company policy that the password is changed monthly.

We host a website that sends email from this domain. So that the email is not mis-identified as spam, we relay the email through the office365 servers, authenticating with a user account.

We don't want to change the password for this account every month.

Here's where I am at:

1. Set users password policy to never expire (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-an-individual-user-s-password-to-never-expire-f493e3af-e1d8-4668-9211-230c245a0466)
2. This requires a server connected to the Azure AD
3. This requires either AD to be publicly accessible, or to spin up a temporary VM in azure
4. This requires "AD Domain Services" to be enabled
5. This requires a "regional virtual network"

Talk about shaving yaks! Where I am stuck is on getting a "regional virtual network" to appear in the drop-down below. Any help would be appreciated. I have a few virtual networks set up but I can't get them to appear in this list.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For now, we can enable Azure AD Domain Services in **a classic Azure virtual network**, and AAD DS **cannot** be enable in virtual networks created using Azure Resource Manager. And ensure that the Azure virtual network you create or choose to use with Azure AD Domain Services belongs to an **[Azure region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services/)** that is **supported** by Azure AD Domain Service.
Also Your Azure AD Domain Services managed domain is deployed **in the same Azure region** as the virtual network you choose to enable the service in.

If your want to use AAD DS with Azure resource manager, you can connect a Resource Manager-based virtual network to a classic virtual network in which Azure AD Domain Services is enabled. Thereafter, you can use Azure AD Domain Services in the Resource Manager-based virtual network. We can use **S2S VPN** or virtual **[network peering](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-networking#network-connectivity).**

More information about Networking considerations for Azure AD Domain Services, refer to the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-networking).

Comment: Yes, I read those same instructions. I don't see any specifics with your answer on HOW. I know that I can spend a few days learning Azure, but that's why I am on superuser.com - so I can shortcut that.

Comment: @Dan Do you create your virtual network in classic module?

Answer (score 0):

Success! OK, here's what I did:

1. Everything must be done in the Classic Azure interface at https://manage.windowsazure.com/
2. Create a Virtual Network in "Central US", "South Central US" or "West Central US" (this may not work for you, just keep creating them until one appears in on the domain settings screen
3. On Domain Settings screen, enable AD Domain services for domain ".onmicrosoft.com", selecting your virtual network
4. Wait around 20 minutes for AD to be set up
5. An IP address will appear on the same screen - this is the AD server, and will be used as the virtual networks DNS
6. Navigate back to your virtual network and add the DNS server - any name will do
7. Reset your password, so that it will be replicated to NTLM/AD
8. Create a Windows VM on your virtual network (must use advanced to select the right virtual network)
9. Once the VM is up, confirm that it's DNS is pointing to your AD server
10. Join AD domain:

    1. domain: company.onmicrosoft.com
    2. user: company\alias
11. Install software at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975125.aspx

    1. Microsoft Online Services Sign-in Assistant for IT Professionals RTW
    2. Windows Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell
12. Reboot
13. Open powershell shortcut on desktop

    1. Connect-MsolService
    2. Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName alias@company.com -PasswordNeverExpires $true